# How to get an Attribute from Each Result of querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do this:

1. Search for all the spans in my structure
2. Get the id value from each span
3. Update the parent  with that text for test purposes

The reason for this work is that I am doing front-end customizations for an application and trying get some WAI-ARIA labelled-by values set on a parent element.

The problem is that many of the needed values come from an COTS application that I am working with/around. These needed input are not always set in a good sequence in the DOM.

I have been looking at a JS solution to get around this.

```
<div class="fluid-form-container">
<ul id="accordionGroup" class="Accordion" data-allow-multiple="">
<li class="fluid-form-group-container">
<h3 aria-labelledby="accordion1id">
<button aria-expanded="true" class="Accordion-trigger" aria-controls="sect1" id="accordion1id">
<span class="Accordion-title"><div class="fluid-form-title">
<div class="FormSection">
<span id="More_Info_Form_Section_Label">More Info</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</button>
</h3>
</li>
<li class="fluid-form-group-container">
<h3 aria-labelledby="accordion2id">
<button aria-expanded="true" class="Accordion-trigger" aria-controls="sect2" id="accordion2id">
<span class="Accordion-title"><div class="fluid-form-title">
<div class="FormSection">
<span id="Even_More_Info_Form_Section_Label">Even More Info</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</button>
</h3>
</li>
</div>

//My bad javaScript so far

var found_elements = [];

var outers = document.querySelectorAll('.FormSection');

for(var i=0; i<outers.length; i++) {
    var elements_in_outer = outers[i].querySelectorAll("span");
  var updateValue = elements_in_outer.getAttr("id");
  outers[i].closest("h3").innerHTML = updateValue;
}
```

The expect results:
- parent  tag innerHTML set to the id value of each span in the structure

Actual results:
- I'm getting errors because I am not sure what I need to use to get that id from each span found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) , so `elements_in_outer.getAttr("id")` won't work and should be replaced with `querySelector()`

there is no `getAttr`, use `getAttribute`

( i replaced your `for` with a `forEach` )

```js
var found_elements = [];

var outers = document.querySelectorAll('.FormSection').forEach(div => {
  var elements_in_outer = div.querySelector("span");
  var updateValue = elements_in_outer.getAttribute("id");
  div.closest("h3").innerHTML = updateValue;
});
```

```html
<div class="fluid-form-container">
  <ul id="accordionGroup" class="Accordion" data-allow-multiple="">
    <li class="fluid-form-group-container">
      <h3 aria-labelledby="accordion1id">
        <button aria-expanded="true" class="Accordion-trigger" aria-controls="sect1" id="accordion1id">
<span class="Accordion-title"><div class="fluid-form-title">
<div class="FormSection">
<span id="More_Info_Form_Section_Label">More Info</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</button>
      </h3>
    </li>
    <li class="fluid-form-group-container">
      <h3 aria-labelledby="accordion2id">
        <button aria-expanded="true" class="Accordion-trigger" aria-controls="sect2" id="accordion2id">
<span class="Accordion-title"><div class="fluid-form-title">
<div class="FormSection">
<span id="Even_More_Info_Form_Section_Label">Even More Info</span>
</div>
</div>
</span>
</button>
      </h3>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know beforehand that you will only use the span elements that have an id, then use [id] in the querySelectorAll selector likewise

```
document.querySelectorAll('span[id]')
```

If you will use that as an array, then you need

```
[... document.querySelectorAll('span[id]')]
```

Assigning the new value would be something like this:

```
[... document.querySelectorAll('span[id]')].forEach(s => s.closest("h3").innerHTML = s.id)
```

Comment: javascript has a `closest()` method?  Or are you confusing jQuery methods with javascript?

Comment: There's a closest method and takes a selector just like querySelector does

Comment: Interesting.  How new is that method?

Comment: It's already in the DOM specification and supported by all modern browsers (of course, IE is not a explorer anymore)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest